# Write plot as png file to s3 bucket r

Tags: r, amazon-s3

I'm using an ec2 instance and want to write a plot as a png file to an s3 bucket. Is there a way to do so directly from the R script without saving the file locally on the vm?

Comment: https://github.com/cloudyr/aws.s3 • specifically https://github.com/cloudyr/aws.s3/blob/master/R/put_object.R#L32-L35

Comment: @hrbrmstr I used put_object for csv files and it worked great. can't seem to get it to work with png files, as writing png files

Comment: have no idea what you did since there's no code.